# getting an embedded resource in a single dll made up of multiple class libraries

Tags: dll, embedded-resource

my solution has multiple projects and in one of them I have the code to get the embedded resource (an xml file) from another project. All this works fine when all the projects are seperate. However when all the class libraries are embedded into a single dll, the code to get the resource file does not work i.e. it cannot get the emebedded resource. 
 I was wondering if the references to the emebedded resource get mixed up when they are combined together in a single dll??

I use the method Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("namespace..filename");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(). I would use typeof(SomeClassNextToXmlFile).Assembly that way if you are calling the dll with the embedded resource from a exe file it won't go looking in the exe for the resource. Also you may want to try using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and make sure the resource you are looking for is where you think it is.